# SignalR and Azure Websites - Remote procedure call not working

Tags: azure, signalr, azure-web-app-service

I am using SignalR for my website, and it works fine when debugging locally. However, whenever I deploy to Azure Websites, the client code is having issues invoking the server code.

I can see the websocket connection successfully getting set up, and I can see OnConnected() being invoked on my server. However, whenever the client Javascript code attempts to invoke a method on the server, it never succeeds. Specifically, I'm seeing this line in the logs:

```
SignalR: Invoking metricshub.StartStreaming
```

But I never see the method actually invoked, nor the log indicating that the method was invoked successfully.

Comment: what do you mean by it never succeed? are you getting any errors in the console? have you tried setting a break point in the function to see if it's actually being called or not?

Comment: I set a breakpoint and a trace call in the function, and I never see either of them trigger. I am also not seeing any errors or logs on the client side beyond the log I posted in my question. If there's any way to get more logging output from SignalR on the server side it would be a big help.

Comment: you can get more logging by adding this in your `web.config` https://gist.githubusercontent.com/davidfowl/4729006/raw/73e46994448fa6fe5ba4e58590231b56d7bf2f25/connection.xml you may want to replace `PersistentConnection` by `Hub` since you are using hubs not persistent connections

Comment: Thanks, I added that to my web.config. Where should I be seeing this additional logging output?

Comment: there should be a file in your website called `signalr.log.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed by using https instead of http. The corporate network where I work was interfering with the SignalR connection when using http. If you are having the same issue, try connecting to your website outside of your corporate network. If that fixes the issue, use https.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have WebSockets enabled for your site? You need that for SignalR to work

To turn on WebSockets go to your website in the portal, and in the Configure tab set "Web Sockets" to ON

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I do have WebSockets enabled, and it looks like it's working. I see this in the logs: SignalR: Connecting to websocket endpoint ... SignalR: Websocket opened. However, the same issue occurs anyway.